# How to Drop to Command Line While Guest OS in Virtualbox

Tags: linux, bash, virtualbox

In most linux guis, there is a command for dropping to the shell.  Most of the time the  ctr + alt + F1 .  But what about when it's a guest os inside virtual box?  I try to use this shortcut and the host drops to the host's terminal, not the guest.

I thought this would be an easy answer to find, but it seems that's not the case.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you want to drop out off X completely, or is an xterm ok?

Comment: Which Linux, running which window manager?

Note that host hotkeys often have to be specially handled to send them to the guest OS. I haven't used Virtualbox so I'm not sure what its mechanism would be for that, but if it does turn out that you need to send that key through, check Vb's docs to find out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `host + F1`? For example, `right ctrl + F1`.